# JavaScript JQuery Galleria.io Zk Framework getSelectedImage() or getIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery, zk, galleria

i have implement a `Image Gallery using javascript,JQuery,Galleria.io library` everything works as expected we are using `Zk Framework` my question is

how can i get the Selected image or selected index to able to delete it in both image gallery and the dataBase here is what i have try so far.

this is how i have created the gallery

```
<script type="text/javascript">Galleria.loadTheme('gallery/galleria.classic.min.js');Galleria.run('#galleria');</script>
```

when zk clicked a button i am calling a javascript snippet like this

```
var index = $('#galleria').getIndex();alert(index);
```

but throws..

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'getIndex' (TypeError)
```

i think knowing the index should be enough for me delete the image i am trying to call this method

```
.getIndex()
returns Number
Returns the current index.
```

See
[API](http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#getindex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getIndex()` method(as well as all other Galleria methods) is stored in Galleria *instance*. So you should obtain the instance first, and then call the method.
The instance stored in jQuery `data`, associated with gallery element.

```
var index = $('#galleria').data('galleria').getIndex();
alert(index);
```